# Can a tablet implement OTG for its own purpose, but prevent apps from using it?

Tags: android, usb-otg

I'm new to `android` programming and my project needs `serial communication` with an `arduino board`. I began with building my very first project by importing the `source code` of [ArduinoUSB](https://github.com/hariharan-m/Arduino-Android-USB).

In this code, I have use the `android device` in `OTG mode` and the `arduino board` is connected as a `slave`. It implements a `pseudo serial device`.
I rather easily succeeded to `communicate` on a `wiko smartphone (android 5.1)`, but I am unable to have it run on a `ezeepad 785 tablet running android 4.1.1`.

I initially thought the `tablet` did not support `OTG`, but actually this is not the case, for if I have connect a `memory stick` on the `tablet` through a `OTG cable`, I can see the files in the stick.

However, whereas on my `wiko phone`, when I have `connect` the `arduino board` for the first time, I got the `dialog` "open `ArduinoUSB` on connection of this `usb device`?", this never happens on my `tablet`.

To investigate, I added `printout` statements in the code to show what methods are activated on connection of the `arduino board`.

Here again, on the `wiko phone` I see on the `screen` my messages signalling that the `broadcast message` was `received`, the `VID` of the `arduino board`, etc.
When I run the same `code` on the `tablet`, nothing happens. No evidence of a `broadcast message` on connection of the `arduino board`.

I have `installed` the `USB OTG` checker application from the `play store`, and again, this app shows my `arduino board` connected on the `wiko phone`, and nothing connected on the `tablet`.

Is it possible that the `tablet` implements a `partial OTG` function that only supports a `memory stick`, and even hide it to another application? for on my `wiko phone`, if I connect a `memory stick`, I can read the `VID` of the stick on the `screen` thanks to the extra prints I added in the `code`. This does not happen on the `tablet`.

I am at my `wit's` end...

Comment: Does your Arduino get power up when you connect it to the tablet?

Comment: Yes it does ! as well as the memory stick.

Comment: Can you post your code when you check for your broadcast receiver and also the part that you check for USB id ?

Comment: Th reason I am asking is that there should be a part in the code where you check for "Device Id" like this: "if (deviceVID != 0x1d6b && (devicePID != 0x0001 && devicePID != 0x0002 && devicePID != 0x0003)". I realized my device ID kept changing everytime so I got rid of that line and everything worked out. You can make a toast that print your device id when you connect the Arduino to see if the device id is what you are checking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Please do not mind its being "quick and dirty" ! :

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { //Broadcast Receiver to automatically start and stop the Serial connection.
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            tvAppend(textView,"BROADCAST RECEIVER\r\n");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)) {
            boolean granted = intent.getExtras().getBoolean(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (granted) {
                connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection);
                if (serialPort != null) {
                    if (serialPort.open()) { //Set Serial Connection Parameters.
                        setUiEnabled(true);
                        serialPort.setBaudRate(9600);
                        serialPort.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8);
                        serialPort.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1);
                        serialPort.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE);
                        serialPort.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
                        serialPort.read(mCallback);
                        tvAppend(textView,"Serial Connection Opened!\n");

                    } else {
                        tvAppend(textView,"SERIAL PORT NOT OPEN");
                    }
                } else {
                    tvAppend(textView,"SERIAL PORT IS NULL");
                }
            } else {
                tvAppend(textView,"SERIAL PERM NOT GRANTED");
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
            onClickStart(startButton);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
            onClickStop(stopButton);
        } else tvAppend(textView,"UNKNOWN ACTION");
    }

    ;
};
```

as you can see, on any broadcast message a sentence is printed in the textview component.
If the message is a usb permission, this code calls in turn the following code:

```
public void onClickStart(View view) {

    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
    if (!usbDevices.isEmpty()) {
        boolean keep = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
            device = entry.getValue();
            int deviceVID = device.getVendorId();
            if (deviceVID == 0x1EAF)//Maple R3   Vendor ID
            {
                int devicePID = device.getProductId() ; // Le PID du BSL est 3
                if ( devicePID == 4 ) {                 // Le PID du port série émulé est 4
                    tvAppend(textView, "\ndevice PID : " + devicePID + "\n");

                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
                    usbManager.requestPermission(device, pi);
                    keep = false;
                }
            } else {
                tvAppend(textView, "\ndevice VID : " + deviceVID + "\n");
                connection = null;
                device = null;
            }

            if (!keep)
                break;
        }
    }
else
    tvAppend(textView, "\nPas de réponse" + "\n");


}
```

where the VID and the PID are checked and messages are printed accordingly. Please note that I said arduino for sake of simplicity, but the board is actually a Olimexino STM32 equivalent to a Maple R3, thus the different VID.
All in all, the main problem is that in my tablet the broadcast receiver is never called when I connect a device on the OTG, whereas this works on my wiko phone. Again, the tablet sees a memory stick connected since the explorer can show its files.
Could the USB traffic be fully intercepted in the tablet firmware in order to prevent a user from exploiting the OTG capability for other purposes?

At compile time, the Android Studio selects API 16 for the tablet and API 22 for the phone. Are there differences between API's that could explain this behavior?

Comment: Where you able to solve the problem? Did you add the necessary permissions and texts in manifest?! For broadcast and USB

Comment: No, I am still at the same point. Do you mean that the permissions could be handled differently in API 16 and API 22? For I confirm that under API 22 this code works perfectly, and as soon as I insert the USB plug I get the popup menu "do you allow the application AndoidUSB to access the USB device" (or equivalent wording, my system is in french). This menu never shows on API 16.

Comment: No I mean do you have these ones in your manifest file?                   <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:required="true" /> and this one goes inside the <application> ,       <service
            android:name=".UsbService"
            android:enabled="true" />

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it more clear:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.someApp">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name=".UsbService"
            android:enabled="true" />



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

TheEngineer, thanks for taking the time of examining my problem.

My manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hariharan.arduinousb" >
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hariharan.arduinousb.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

As you see:
in uses-feature, the .required parameter is missing. I added it.
The /service block is also missing. I try to add it, but got an "unresolved class reference" error. In the .zip of the project I downloaded (see link above) this statement is absent.

However, after this correction, the behavior is the same: the USB device is detected on API 22 and not on API 16.